# Writing "None" to a file in python

Tags: python, file, io, null

I have a txt file that contains rows of JSON objects.
I'm parsing this file in Python, and I'm writing a file that every row in it will be a record (Comma separated) I've built from the JSON object.

Now, when I'm building this file - some of the values can be Null (or None in Python). So this is what I write:

```
a = 'abc'
b = None
str = a + "," + b
file.write(str+\n)
```

But I keep getting this error: 
`TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found`

So my question is - How can I write "Null" values into the file, in a string, so when I load the file into the table - the value in that position will actually be Null?
How can I keep this value in a file?

Thank you!

Comment: You can only handle strings in CSV files. So, `None` should be replaced by an empty string. Is is OK for you to have "" instead of `None`?

Comment: You can only accept one answer, did you accept the right one? (I was notified you accepted mine first)

Comment: The CSV file helped me handle this - so I checked you both... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's Ok for you to have an empty string when you have `None` value, you can write:

```
a = 'abc'
b = None
row = a + "," + (b or "")
file.write(row + "\n")
```

*Please, don't use `str` as a variable name because you shadow a built-in function/class*

Or more generally, if you have a list of items:

```
items = ['abc', None]
row = [(item or "") for item in items]
file.write(",".join(row) + "\n")
```

Or use the [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

With JSON, you could also have integers, `list` and `dict`. To convert that in string for a serialization in CSV, you could use:

```
def to_string(obj):
    if obj is None:
        return ""
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, dict)):
        raise TypeError(repr(type(obj)))
    else:
        return str(obj)

row = [to_string(item) for item in items]
file.write(",".join(row) + "\n")
```

*Here, `list` and `dict` serialization is prohibited.*

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.format`.

```
a = 'abc'
b = None
file.write("{},{}\n".format(a, b))
```

The error you get is in the line above `file.write`. When concatenating items to form a string, *all* items being concatenated *must* also be a string. This would mean, you'd need to do something along the lines of:

```
string = a + ',' + str(b)
file.write(string + '\n')
```

It is worth noting that you shouldn't use `str`, `dict`, or `list` to name variables as it shadows the inbuilt classes with the same name.

---

You might also consider using `NaN`, or, as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269059/writing-none-value-in-a-file-python#comment79500730_46269059) just have an empty string `""` instead of `None`. Furthermore, look into the `csv` module on how to write to a CSV file. Here's an example from the [`csv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```